# Помогите составить SQLite запрос

Tags: php, sqlite

Не могу понять, что неправильно делаю. Не работает мой SQLite запрос:

```
`area` LIKE "Петровский%" AND `address` NOT LIKE "NULL"
```

Если пишу:

```
`area` LIKE "Петровский%"
```

то все работает.

Но как только пытаюсь внести дополнительное условие

```
AND `address` NOT LIKE "NULL"
```

запрос перестает работать.

Полностью это выглядит так:

```
<?php foreach(list('`area` LIKE "Петровский%"') as $item):?>
```

Мне нужно исключить все данные из таблицы list, где в поле address значится NULL, а район, соответственно, Петровский

Спасибо!

Comment: address IS NOT NULL

Comment: СПАСИБО! А если значение поля, допустим, "ДОП" - именно так, на кириллице, как мне его можно исключить?

Comment: Либо `<> "ДОП"`, либо `NOT LIKE "ДОП"`

Comment: `AND address <> 'ДОП'`

Comment: Изучи синтаксис. Для начала, чем `NOT NULL` отличается от `NOT "NULL"`

Comment: Да оно мне понадобилось раз в жизни. Я seo-шник, вообще-то. Остальное - если уж очень понадобилось. Но, может, когда-нибудь и дойдет очередь.